# iOS - How to stop background music when changing views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, audio

How to stop background music when changing views? I have no clue. If i press a button which takes me to a new view, there is new background music. But the old background music (which goes in an infinite loop) keeps on going. Please help! also sample some code please, here is mine:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathMusic2" ofType:@"wav"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I just need to know how to make the background music from the new view stop playing. And vice versa when i press the back button from the new view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a property for the `AVAudioPlayer *theAudio` so you can access the audioPlayer from any point in your class.

**Header file of viewController**

```
... 
AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

**Implentation file of viewController**

```
...
@synthesize theAudio;
...

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MathMusic2" ofType:@"wav"];
    self.theAudio= [[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL]] autorelease];
    theAudio.delegate = self;
    [theAudio play];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

If viewWillDisappear is called you can then just stop the audio with

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
    [theAudio stop];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it gaves errors in here : 
    "theAudio.delegate = self;" as something like assigning to id...

its yellow anyway..
still when i change view and go to another class music not stoping....

Comment: add AVAudioPlayerDelegate in viewController.h