# xcode sprite kit background music

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I have a game I made using sprite kit and I have added a 30 second audio file to loop infinitely as background music for my game using av audio player. When the game switches from a certain state i want to stop and start the music from the my scene file.

This is my view controller.m file where I have added a stop music method

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    NSError *error;
    NSURL *backgroundMusicUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"game" withExtension:@"wav"];
    _backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicUrl error:&error];
    _backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops =  -1;
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer play];

    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}

-(void)stopMusic
{
    [_backgroundMusicPlayer pause];
}
```

and then in my my scene.m file I have tried to call the stop music method however the background music does not stop playing.

```
-(void)switchToTutorial{

    [[ViewController alloc] stopMusic];

    _gameState = GameStateTutorial;

    //remove unwatnted nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < _mainMenu.count; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *chosenNode = [_mainMenu objectAtIndex:i];
        [chosenNode removeFromParent];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < _mainMenuButtons.count; i++)
    {
        SKSpriteNode *chosenNode = [_mainMenuButtons objectAtIndex:i];
        [chosenNode removeFromParent];
    }
    [self setupTutorial];
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764890/ios-how-to-stop-background-music-when-changing-views you need to create an additional property so you can access the music from anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
[[ViewController alloc] stopMusic];
```

You are creating a new instance of ViewController, but should send the stopMusic message to the current used one.

A way to achieve this, would be to have a property of type ViewController in your scene and set the viewController to it.

In MyScene.h

```
@class ViewController; //below the #import
...
@property(weak) ViewController *viewController;
```

In MyScene.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
...
[self.viewController stopMusic]
```

In ViewController.m

```
MyScene * scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
scene.viewController = self;
```

The problem of this approach is you will have to pass the ViewController for each scene. Maybe it would be easier to have a static `AVAudioPlayer` and two static methods to start and stop the music, then you could just call

```
[ViewController stopMusic];
```

If you have arrived in that stage, you could think about creating an extra class, i.e. MusicPlayer to handle all music for you. So you would call something like

```
// in ViewControllers viewDidLoad
[MusicPlayer initializePlayer];

//where needed
[MusicPlayer playMusic];
[MusicPlayer stopMusic];
```

Comment: After declaring the viewController property in myscene.h I still am not able to reference it in the view controller.m like you said to. and then it is not letting me make the stop music call in my scene.m to the property.

Comment: sorry, *scene must of course be declared as MyScene, so the compiler knows that it's a MyScene. I modified the code.

Comment: Did you declare the `-(void)stopMusic;` in the ViewController.h? otherwise the scene doesn't know that the viewController has such a method.

Comment: the compiler keeps making me list the viewController property as an object of UIviewcontroller instead of just "ViewController" like you have in your code? would this be a problem because i still can not get the music to pause when i call [[ViewController alloc] stopMusic];

Comment: Haha of course you should call [self.viewController stopMusic] then... Just import ViewController.h in myscene so the compiler knows about its existence and methods

Comment: Thanks for upvoting or accepting the answer if it was helpful. ;)